# iOS - UILabel Showing auto bottom border

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

I have add one UILabel in one UIView. I have not added any border or shadow to it. But still it showing that.

And Main problem is, Shadow or Border is not updating while orientation change.

Please refer following images:

**Portrait Mode Label**

[image]

**Landscape Mode Label**

[image]

**Constraints Of Label:**

[image]

[image]

**Constraints of Superview:**

[image]

**I don't want that Shadow or border over there**

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting the BG color to clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the background colour of its superviews and try to give clear colour to label.

Comment: I have set background as `clearColor` only to the label.